# Redirect to external URL with Lumen

Tags: php, lumen

how can I do an external redirect (and set header values) with Lumen? This is not working:

```
return redirect()->away('http://www.away.com');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just

`return redirect()->to('http://www.away.com');`

or simply

`return redirect('http://www.away.com');`

should work.

---

From the source of `redirect`:

```
 * @param  string|null  $to
 * @param  int     $status
 * @param  array   $headers
 * @param  bool    $secure
 * @return \Laravel\Lumen\Http\Redirector|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
function redirect($to = null, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
```

Comment: Ah ok found it. I've used a IP adress for redirection (without http://).